# Does Alvin Plantinga's book Knowledge and Christian Belief offer any substantial updates to Warranted Christian Belief?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-religion, christianity, plantinga

The stated primary goal of Plantinga's *Knowledge and Christian Belief* (2015) was to condense the content of *Warranted Christian Belief* (2000) into a shorter and more accessible book.

My question is whether the explanations and arguments from *Warranted Christian Belief* have been substantially refined in the new book, to address or otherwise work around objections that have been raised during the fifteen years between the two publications?

Is there any intellectual benefit to reading *Knowledge and Christian Belief* instead of *Warranted Christian Belief*, apart from the lower time investment requirement?